# How can I inject Spring Batch's StepExecution into Generic Rest Client using Web Client?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-webclient

I have a generic rest client that is being used to handle 4xx and 5xx errors in a Spring Batch app.  When the apis fail, I want to add to the step execution context inside of handle4xxError and handle5xxError.

```
public class RestClient<T> {
    private final WebClient webClient;
    public Mono<T> execute(Class<T> responseClass) {
         webClient
               .method(method)
               .uri(uri)
               .retrieve()
               .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, clientResponse -> handle4xxError(clientResponse))
               .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxServerError, clientResponse -> handle5xxError(clientResponse))
               .bodyToMono(responseClass)

    }

    private Mono<? extends Throwable> handle4xxError(ClientResponse clientResponse) {
        Mono<String> errorMessage = clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class);
        return errorMessage.flatMap(message -> {
            String clientException = "4xx Error Response code is " + clientResponse.statusCode() + " and the message is " + message;
            log.error(clientException);
            return Mono.error(new ClientException(clientException));
        });
    }

}
```

I am injecting RestClient inside my api service

```
public class ApiService {
    private final RestClient<ApiResponse> restClient
    public Mono<ApiResponse> getApiResponse () {
         return restClient.execute(ApiResponse.class)
    }
}
```

and auto wiring the service in processor.java like

```
class ItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor {
    @Autowired
    private ApiService apiService;
    @BeforeStep
    public void saveStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        stepExecutionContext = stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
    }
    @Override
    public String process(String id) {
    apiService.getApiResponse().block()
    return ...;
    }
}
```

how can i pass executionContext down so i can edit it in the handleError methods inside the RestClient class. like such

```
    private Mono<? extends Throwable> handle4xxError(ClientResponse clientResponse) {
        Mono<String> errorMessage = clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class);
        return errorMessage.flatMap(message -> {
            String clientException = "4xx Error Response code is " + clientResponse.statusCode() + " and the message is " + message;
            log.error(clientException);
            stepExecution.put("error", clientException")
            return Mono.error(new ClientException(clientException));
        });
    }
```

tried injecting stepexecution but getting "bean not found"

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is correct, but not complete. You need keep a reference to the `StepExecution` and use it when needed in your item processor:

```
@Component
class MyItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private ApiService apiService;

    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @BeforeStep
    public void saveStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @Override
    public String process(String id) {
        // use this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext() as needed
        apiService.getApiResponse().block();
        return ...;
    }

}
```

This is documented here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps

Comment: Thanks, i have that actually. my question was more how do i use StepExecution inside handle4xxError and handle5xxError methods? updated question